# module 'pyshark' has no attribute 'Filecapture'

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, pyshark

I am trying to use pyshark and I am fairly new to the field. But I am encountering this error " module 'pyshark' has no attribute 'Filecapture' ", Even though I am importing pyshark, I am getting the same error, I have even tried running it with sudo from the terminal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You probably want to run this in a virtualenv. You should read up on them: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: Thank you Ross, turns out I made a silly mistake, Filecapture instead of FileCapture, sorry for such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You must run it outside python. Try: python .\mypyscript.py .\mypycap.pcap or try to create a virtual environment  https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html